# Plot failing when given a list of functions

Tags: plotting

I wrote a code which plots a Maclaurin expansion of cos(x) in various degrees.

```
f[x_] := Cos[x]
Animate[
  Plot[Evaluate @ Normal[Series[f[x], {x, 0, s}]],{x, -10 Pi, 10 Pi},
    PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], 
  {s, 0, 80, 2}]
```

This code works well. Next, I just added the original function to Plot, but it does not work.

```
f[x_] := Cos[x]
Animate[
  Plot[{Evaluate @ Normal[Series[f[x], {x, 0, s}]], f[x]}, {x, -10 Pi, 10 Pi},
    PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], 
  {s, 0, 80, 2}]
```

I found that just one function in the List style is also not work correctly.

```
Plot[{Evaluate @ Normal[Series[f[x], {x, 0, 20}]]}, {x, -10 Pi, 10 Pi},
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

What's wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Works in 10.0.0,win 7.

Comment: Thanks all for quick reply! I solved the problem! I note that this problem was under V8.

Comment: m_goldberg
And thank you again for correcting my poor English!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In V9 (and earlier I presume), `Evaluate` has to be the head of the argument for which pre-evaluation is wanted. In your example `List` is the head. See the 2 nd point under Details in[`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluate.html).

You can fix your code by moving `Evaluate` so that it is the head of the first argument to `Plot`

```
Plot[Evaluate@{Normal[Series[f[x], {x, 0, 20}]], f[x]}, {x, -10 Pi, 10 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dotted},
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

In V10, `Plot` seems to be doing evaluation differently and your example works as is.